# Selenium Python Code Only Scrapes Links from First Page of Paginated Website

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, automation

I'm working on a web scraping project in Python using Selenium to extract links from a paginated website. The goal is to scrape links from multiple pages of the website. I've configured my code to navigate through the pagination and extract links, but I'm encountering an issue where the code only scrapes links from the first page and then closes the browser.

Here's the relevant part of my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def scrape_links(url):
    firefox_options = Options()
    firefox_options.binary_location = "/usr/lib/firefox-esr/firefox-bin"
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=firefox_options)

    all_hrefs = []
    current_page = 1

    while True:
        driver.get(url)
        html_content = driver.page_source
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, "html.parser")
        play_links = soup.select(
            "section.main article.page-detail div.content-wrapper div.episode-list-wrapper div.episode-list div.episode-wrap div.episode div.episode-snapshot a.play"
        )
        hrefs = [link.get("href") for link in play_links]
        all_hrefs.extend(hrefs)
        # Find the "next page" button
        try:
            next_page_button = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "section.main article.page-detail div.content-wrapper div.episode-list-wrapper nav ul.pagination li.page-item:not(.disabled) a.page-link")

            if next_page_button:
                next_page_button.click()
                current_page += 1
                url = f"{url}?page={current_page}"
            else:
                break 
        except:
            break

    title_span = soup.select_one(
        "section.main article.page-detail div.header-wrapper header.anime-header div.title-wrapper h1 span"
    )
    website_title = title_span.get_text() if title_span else "Unknown Title"

    driver.quit()

    with open(f"{website_title}.txt", "w") as file:
        for href in all_hrefs:
            file.write("https://animepahe.ru" + href + "\n")

    print(f"Links have been saved for {website_title}")
num_links = int(input("Enter the number of animepahe webpages: "))
urls = []
for i in range(num_links):
    url = input(f"Enter URL {i+1}: ")
    urls.append(url)
for url in urls:
    scrape_links(url)
```

I've made sure that the code identifies and clicks the "next page" button correctly. However, it seems that after clicking the button, the scraping process doesn't continue on the subsequent pages. The browser closes as soon as the first page is scraped. I'm unable to figure out what's causing this behavior.

Could someone please review my code and point out what I might be missing? Is there a mistake in the way I'm using Selenium or handling the page navigation? Any help or suggestions on how to fix this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: How about printing the exception prior to line 36 and while we are at it, maybe print, debug the while loop in general. I suspect that content on the pages is being loaded async and you might need to `WebDriverWait()`

Comment: Note sure if the project is to scrape just using Selenium, but there are more efficient ways to get this data using the backend api that generates the data: https://animepahe.ru/api?m=airing&page=1  you can loop over the page numbers

Comment: @JonSG, can you explain further

Answer (score 0):

After you click the "next page" button, you are overriding the url variable with `url = f"{url}?page={current_page}"`. This is redundant since clicking the button should already take you to the next page. Revisiting the URL after you've clicked the button might be causing the browser to load the first page again. You can remove the URL manipulation step.

You could try to something like this;

```
def scrape_links(url):
    firefox_options = Options()
    firefox_options.binary_location = "/usr/lib/firefox-esr/firefox-bin"
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=firefox_options)

    all_hrefs = []

    while True:
        driver.get(url)
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.play"))
        )
        html_content = driver.page_source
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, "html.parser")
        play_links = soup.select(
            "section.main article.page-detail div.content-wrapper div.episode-list-wrapper div.episode-list div.episode-wrap div.episode div.episode-snapshot a.play"
        )
        hrefs = [link.get("href") for link in play_links]
        all_hrefs.extend(hrefs)

        # Try to find the "next page" button and click it
        try:
            next_page_button = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "section.main article.page-detail div.content-wrapper div.episode-list-wrapper nav ul.pagination li.page-item:not(.disabled) a.page-link")
            next_page_button.click()
            WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
                EC.staleness_of(next_page_button)
            )
        except:
            break

    title_span = soup.select_one(
        "section.main article.page-detail div.header-wrapper header.anime-header div.title-wrapper h1 span"
    )
    website_title = title_span.get_text() if title_span else "Unknown Title"

    driver.quit()

    with open(f"{website_title}.txt", "w") as file:
        for href in all_hrefs:
            file.write("https://animepahe.ru" + href + "\n")

    print(f"Links have been saved for {website_title}")
```

Comment: Using your solution causes the browser to go back and forth between page 1 and page 2 on the website. Also, my problem with the code I posted is that it only loads page one and scrapes data from only page one rather than proceeding to the other pages till there is no page left